# Qt widget app - different layouts based on orientation

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a qt widgets app that needs to rearrange itself if the screen orientation is portrait vs landscape or if the window is resized to be taller than it is wide. The app has all the same widgets and functionality in both modes, just laid out differently.

I realize you can move widgets around in layouts at runtime based on resize events, but this alone is not ideal because you can't see what it will look like beforehand in the designer. I also found this example in the archives: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-orientation-example.html where they have two separate UIs can choose which to show when the screen resizes, but in this case every single UI change, slot connection, etc. must be done to both UIs which is also extremely cumbersome, not scalable, and error prone.

Is there a clean way to handle this situation? Or at least visualize both modes without running the app? Qt version is 5.12+

Answer (score 0):

You could - theoretically - create 2 files or objects. One would be myLandscapeWidget and other myPortraitWidget. Surround them with a Loader and could do a

```
Loader {
    id: myLoader
    anchors.fill: parent
    sourceComponent: Screen.orientation === Qt.LandscapeOrientation ? land : port

    Component {
        id: land
        myLandscapeWidget {
            width: 500
            height: 100
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: port
        myPortraitWidget {
            width: 100
            height: 500
            visible: Screen.orientation !== Qt.LandscapeOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

Well, atleast thats the gist of it...
Some links:
[Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#sourceComponent-prop) ,  [Screen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html)

Comment: I'm not using qml though...also wouldn't this approach still require duplicating button handling code, etc for each widget?

Comment: ah, my bad then. Never used widgets before.
It would require repositioning and copying code, yes. But you can create seperate files to not make your code duplicate, include it and use the code from there. You could also use anchors and relative margins based on screen which would also reposition them nicely